# How to make a Q_ENUM from C++ work as options for a ComboBox in QML

Tags: combobox, qml, qt6

I am using `Qt6.5.1` and I have created `ComboBox` in QML. Following is what I have done.

I have following C++ class.

```
class MyComboBoxOptions : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList options READ options)
public:     

    QStringList options() const {
        return mComboOptionStrings;
    }

private:
    const QStringList mComboOptionStrings {
        "Option 1",
        "Option 2",
        "Option 3",
    };
};
```

In `main.cpp` I have done the following to register the above class MyComboBoxOptions in QML.

```
MyComboBoxOptions myComboBoxOptions;
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("myComboBoxOptions", &myComboBoxOptions);
```

Then I have the `ComboBox` like below in QML.

```
ComboBox {
    id: comboBox
    height: 20
    width: 50

    model: myComboBoxOptions.options
    currentIndex: 0 // default
}
```

**Question:**
How can replace the `QStringList` returned by `MyComboBoxOptions::options` with a `Q_ENUM`? Simply returning a `Q_ENUM` there does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[REWRITE]

I have a general-purpose `EnumInfo` class that can build a model for an enum from any object, including Qt's objects. In the following example, I am accessing PetUtils's `Pet` enum and Qt's Image's `FillMode` enum:

```cpp
// PetUtils.h
#ifndef PETUTILS_H
#define PETUTILS_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlEngine>
class PetUtils : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
public:
    explicit PetUtils(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }
    enum Pet
    {
        Cat,
        Dog,
        Parrot
    };
    Q_ENUMS(Pet)
};
#endif // PETUTILS_H
```

```
// main.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtEnumApp

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ColumnLayout {
        Label { text: "Choose a Pet type" }
        // "Cat", "Dog", "Parrot"
        ComboBox {
            model: petEnum.keyValues
            textRole: "key"
            valueRole: "value"
        }
        Label { text: "Choose an Image FillMode" }
        // "Stretch", "PreserveAspectFit", "PreserveAspectCrop", "Tile", "TileVertically", "TileHorizontally", "Pad"
        ComboBox {
            model: fillModeEnum.keyValues
            textRole: "key"
            valueRole: "value"
        }
        Image {
            id: image
        }
    }
    PetUtils { id: petUtils }
    EnumInfo { id: petEnum; obj: petUtils; enumName: "Pet" }
    EnumInfo { id: fillModeEnum; obj: image; enumName: "FillMode" }
}
```

The way this works is that the `EnumInfo` uses the metaObject to look up any enum from any object you give it and it can extract the enum keys (i.e. strings) and enum values (i.e. integer values).

1. ptrQObject->metaObject() // QMetaObject for any QObject
2. metaObject()->indexOfEnumerator(name) // finds an enum index
3. metaObject()->enumerator(index) // QMetaEnum from QMetaObject
4. walk the key/values from QMetaEnum

```cpp
// EnumInfo.h
#ifndef ENUMINFO_H
#define ENUMINFO_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlEngine>
class EnumInfo : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant obj MEMBER m_var NOTIFY enumChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString enumName MEMBER m_enumName NOTIFY enumChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant keyValues READ keyValues NOTIFY enumChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QStringList keys READ keys NOTIFY enumChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant values READ values NOTIFY enumChanged)
public:
    explicit EnumInfo(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }
    Q_INVOKABLE int keyToValue(const QString& key)
    {
        QMetaEnum metaEnum = getMetaEnum();
        if (!metaEnum.isValid()) return -1;
        return metaEnum.keyToValue(key.toUtf8());
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE QString valueToKey(int value)
    {
        QMetaEnum metaEnum = getMetaEnum();
        if (!metaEnum.isValid()) return QString();
        return QString::fromUtf8(metaEnum.valueToKey(value));
    }
protected:
    QVariant keyValues() const
    {
        QMetaEnum metaEnum = getMetaEnum();
        if (!metaEnum.isValid()) return QVariant();
        QVariantList list;
        for (int i = 0; i < metaEnum.keyCount(); i++)
        {
            QVariantMap map;
            map["key"] = QString::fromUtf8(metaEnum.key(i));
            map["value"] = metaEnum.value(i);
            list.append(map);
        }
        return list;
    }
    QStringList keys() const
    {
        QMetaEnum metaEnum = getMetaEnum();
        if (!metaEnum.isValid()) return QStringList();
        QStringList list;
        for (int i = 0; i < metaEnum.keyCount(); i++)
            list.append(QString::fromUtf8(metaEnum.key(i)));
        return list;
    }
    QVariant values() const
    {
        QMetaEnum metaEnum = getMetaEnum();
        if (!metaEnum.isValid()) return QVariant();
        QVariantList list;
        for (int i = 0; i < metaEnum.keyCount(); i++)
            list.append(metaEnum.value(i));
        return list;
    }
    QMetaEnum getMetaEnum() const
    {
        if (!m_var.isValid() || m_var.isNull()) return QMetaEnum();
        QObject* obj = qvariant_cast<QObject*>(m_var);
        if (!obj) return QMetaEnum();
        int index = obj->metaObject()->indexOfEnumerator(m_enumName.toUtf8());
        if (index == -1) return QMetaEnum();
        return obj->metaObject()->enumerator(index);
    }
signals:
    void enumChanged();
private:
    QVariant m_var;
    QString m_enumName;
};
#endif // ENUMINFO_H
```

```
# CMakeLists.txt
qt_add_qml_module(appQtEnumApp
    URI QtEnumApp
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES Main.qml
    SOURCES EnumInfo.h PetUtils.h
)
```

Comment: Will it possible to get a basic code example of what you explain?

Comment: Rewrite answer. Now there is a refactored EnumInfo object. Can be used to generate a model for any enumerator, including Qt's.

Comment: Hey, that's a pretty cool class! I might use that myself. My only comment is that you seem to be using the Qt5 style code (qmlRegisterType vs QML_ELEMENT, and `import QtQuick 2.15`) when the post says he's using 6.5.1.

Comment: @JarMan thanks. I've updated the answer to be Qt6.x compliant.